# MIME type check via SFTP connection

Tags: bash, mime-types, sftp

I want to list images by SFTP and save this list, so another script may further process it.

Unfortunately, there are also many other files there, so I need to identify which are images. I am filtering out everything with wrong file extension, but I would like to go a step further and check also the content of the file.

Downloading everything to check it with `file --mime-type` on local machine is too slow. Is there a way how to check MIME type of a file on remote SFTP *before* the download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a way, downloading only first 64 bytes. It is a lot faster than downloading whole file, but still enough to see if it looks like an image:

```
curl "sftp://sftp.example.com/path/to/file.png" -u login:pass -o img.tmp -r 0-64
file --mime-type img.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

MIME type is supported by SFTP version 6 and newer only.

Most SFTP clients and servers, including the most widespread one, OpenSSH, support SFTP version 3 only.

Even the servers that I know of to support SFTP version 6, like Bitvise or ProFTPD `mod_sftp`, do not support the "MIME type" attribute.

So while in theory it's possible to determine MIME type of remote files over SFTP, in practice, you won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any command remotely using ssh:

```
ssh <destination> '<command_to_run>'
```

In this case that would be something like:

```
ssh <remote_machine_name_or_ip_address>  'file --mime-type ./*'
```

Comment: While this might be a solution, it does not use SFTP protocol. It won't work if the account does not have a shell access or if the remote system is not *nix.

Comment: Sadly, we don't have shell access. But I agree this would be the easies solution if we had it.

Comment: You are able to do "scp" but not "ssh" ?

Comment: No. It looks like I really need to use SFTP protocol only. Question edited to reflect this new fact.